# Exporting Oracle schema with DBMS_DATAPUMP does not export ctx_ddl preference and does not create ctxsys.context index type

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, plsql, datapump

We implemented a procedure to export a database schema using DBMS_DATAPUMP. In the schema, we have a CTX_PREFERENCES to use SUBSTRING_INDEX attribute for a ctxsys.context index type on a certain table. When the import has performed in a new database, neither the ctxsys.context index type neither the CTX_PREFERENCES were imported.

Part of the procedure.

```
PROCEDURE backup(p_target_schemas IN VARCHAR2,
        p_filename IN VARCHAR2)
    AS
        l_handler NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        l_handler := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open (operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name => 'EXM', version => '11.2');

        DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file (handle =>l_handler, filename => p_filename, directory =>'DATA_PUMP_DIR');

        DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_filter(handle => l_handler, name => 'SCHEMA_EXPR', value => 'IN(' || p_target_schemas || ')');

        DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job (l_handler);
...
...
...
```

Is there something missing to export the CTX_PREFERENCES and that index?

Comment: Does the My Oracle Support document "Why after Export/Import All User Text Index Preferences Are Lost ? (Doc ID 468599.1)" apply here?  That document implies that `ctx_report.create_index_script` can help.  (But I don't have much practical experience with Oracle Text, so this is just a guess.)

Comment: Hi Jon, seems to be related with I described but I can not check the solution because is asking me for a Support Identifier to show more information.